# How do I get a field to display something based on a selection from a drop down list in Infopath?

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online

How do I have a field display specific text based off a selection in a drop down list?

I have a table with one column containing a drop down list and another column where I want some text to display based off the selection from the drop down list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Rules to achieve that. Example: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/add-rules-for-validation-HA101783369.aspx Is that what you searched for?